# Connecting SQL Server as an External Data Source

Tags: lightning-connect

What is the most efficient means for using SQL Server as an External Data Source in Salesforce? We are using SQL Server 2012. I realize I can create a services project to act as a go between but looking for a solution that doesn't require coding if possible.

I would like full CRUD capabilities from Salesforce to my SQL Server data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot directly connect SQL Server Using External data Source. But it is possible to create an OData Wrapper around SQL Server and then connecting to SQL Server using OData. See below link for exposing SQL Server as an OData Server.

> http://seroter.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/exposing-on-premise-sql-server-tables-as-odata-through-windows-azure-appfabric/

Comment: Thank you anmrk. However, I think you forgot to post the actual link. Would you mind updating your answer?

Answer (score 1):

I used DataDirect Cloud for my Lightning Connect POC with our on-premise data warehouse and it supports SQL Server.
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/03/external-objects-lightning-connect-poc-in-5-days.html

We are also awaiting write support for some future integration projects.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like CRUD is not possible at this Stage, It is Read only at this time. Need to Check with you Saleforce Account Exe